# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web

I'm trying to insert a whole HTML element by clicking on a button, and it actually works, but it should be a draggable element, just as the manually inserted on the HTML as a sample, but when a try to drag it I got this error on the console: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Here's how the drag function was written:

```
dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
        e.preventDefault
        const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(dropzone, e.clientY)
        if (afterElement == null) {
            dropzone.appendChild(draggable)
        } else {
            dropzone.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement)
        }
    })
})
```

Here's how I'm trying to add the element:

```
addTaskButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let title = prompt('Set the title');
    let description = prompt('Set the description');
    const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

    let html = 
    <div class="draggable card" draggable="true">
        <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card-header">
                <p>${date}</p>
                <div class="card-bullet"></div>
            </div>
        
            <h2 id="task-title">${title}</h2>
            <div class="task-members">
                <div class="task-member img"></div>
                <div class="task-member img"></div>
                <div class="task-member add"></div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="task-text">
                <h3>Description</h3>
                <p>${description}.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

    board.innerHTML += html
})
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi Filipe and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where is  the `draggable` class set on the card being dragged - and does logging `document.querySelector('.dragging')` on the console confirm it is a (`.card-wrapper`) element?`

Comment: It's logging null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is most probably because the node (first parameter) that you want to insert in DOM is null or undefined.
You can reproduce this error by running:

```js
document.body.insertBefore(null, document.body.firstChild);
```

You must check the line that returns the element reference to `draggable` :

```
document.querySelector('.dragging') // must be not null, you can run in console and/or debug using the devtools to see what is happening
```

Comment: It's logging null, any idea of what I need to do? The class dragging should be added only when the event 'dragstart' is running, but it doesn't work, if I put it manually it works, but not when I try to add through this 'click' event.

Comment: is because the element does not exists in document, I'm looking to your html code and if you want to get the "draggable="true"" element, you can change the line `document.querySelector('.dragging')` to `document.querySelector('.draggable')` (for class name) or `document.querySelector('[draggable="true"]')` (for attribute)

Comment: Thanks, it started working, now I'm adjusting the other details :D